# .net listView cells properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview with values that look similar to:

```
1 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 1
```

where each entry is one cell/column in the listview.

How can I perform a check if the cell's value is 1, then change the column background colour to something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Eval` and a ternary operator:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .Value1
    { 
       font: 10pt Verdana; 
       font-weight:700;
       color: Green;
    }

    .NotValue1
    { 
       font: 15pt Times; 
       font-weight:250;
       color: Blue;
    }
</style>

<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" >
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server" id="table1" >
      <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" ></tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server">
      <td runat="server" CssClass='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Value"))==1 ? "Value1" : "NotValue1" %>'>
        <%-- Data-bound content. --%>
        <asp:Label ID="LblValue" runat="server" 
          Text='<%#Eval("Value") %>' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

(untested)

Comment: I'm getting: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'
 from the above

Comment: @sd_dracula: Then use [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys.aspx) (if it's an `int`) instead. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I have got it running but I am not seeing any changes in the text formatting. My <TD>: <td runat="server" cssclass='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("troubleshooting"))==1 ? "Value1" : "NotValue1" %>'>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTShooting" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("troubleshooting") %>' />
                </td>  any idea why? The <style> is within the <asp:content> of the aspx, thats fine right?

Comment: @sd_dracula: Have you looked at the html source of the page to see which css class was applied and if at all? You could for example use firebug to inspect the css.

Comment: If I set bgcolor to <tr> it does show the new bgcolor. Perhaps the logic is not firing? All I want is to change bgcolor if the value is = 1